# Setting up copyright footer in JS

Tags: javascript, font-awesome-5

I am trying to setup Font Awesome footer with JS so I can add it to the footer, but unable to, because it shows up as `[object HTMLElement] 2020 - 2021`. I have imported the script for Font Awesome but its not working.

I would like the footer to show as © 2020 - 2021 but to use the Font Awesome logo instead.

```js
document.body.onload = footer;

function footer() {
    // create a new div element
    const footerDiv = document.createElement("footer");

    // assign it a class
    footerDiv.classList.add("footer");

    // gets the current date
    const copyright = new Date().getFullYear();

    // gets the copyright symbol
    const favicon = document.createElement("i");
    favicon.classList.add("fas.fa-copyright");

    const completedFooter = document.createTextNode(favicon +
        " 2020 " + "- " + copyright);

    // add the text node to the newly created div
    footerDiv.appendChild(completedFooter);

    // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM
    const newDiv = document.getElementById("div");
    document.body.insertBefore(footerDiv, newDiv);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/js/all.min.js">   </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Because you can not add a DOM element and a string together.... You should be appending the elements, not setting it in the text node

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the element, not add it as text to a text node. You are also adding the classes wrong to the `i` element.

```js
document.body.onload = footer;

function footer() {
    // create a new div element
    const footerDiv = document.createElement("footer");

    // assign it a class
    footerDiv.classList.add("footer");

    // gets the current date
    const copyright = new Date().getFullYear();

    // gets the copyright symbol
    const favicon = document.createElement("i");
    favicon.classList.add("fas", "fa-copyright");

    const text = document.createTextNode(" 2020 " + "- " + copyright);

    // add the text node to the newly created div
    footerDiv.appendChild(favicon);
    footerDiv.appendChild(text);

    // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM
    const newDiv = document.getElementById("div");
    document.body.insertBefore(footerDiv, newDiv);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```